# Display name for sendmai

Tags: linux, sendmail

I have mails coming from RHEL machine with from address `XYZ[no-auto-replies@abc.com]`and no display name. Please let me know If I can add a display name as XYZ and only mail address as`no-auto-replies@abc.com`. In simple terms I want display name for mail as XYZ and from mail address as no-auto-replies@abc.com

Please do not tell me any changes in configuration of /etc/hosts stuffs in internet because I do not have privileges cannot change settings.

Below is the code am using. This will help me a lot

```
$to = 'abc@xyz.com';
$from = "XYZ[no-auto-replies@abc.com]";
$subject = "ABC";
$message  = "Check mail";
open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
# Email Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
# Email Body
print MAIL $message;
close(MAIL);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "no display name" but your `From:` header certainly contains a syntax error as it is now.  You seem to want something like

```
From: <xyz@example.com>
```

or just

```
From: xyz@example.com
```

(compare with the `To:` header which you are already setting this way)
whereas the correct syntax for a header with a display name would be

```
From: Your Name <xyz@example.com>
```

where you may need [RFC2047](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2047) wrapping if the full name contains characters which are not pure 7-bit US-ASCII.